# Drop off library permission

Tags: permissions, drop-off-library

My client has a drop off library on a site collection (HR) which is separate to their Intranet. Users can send documents to this drop off library, however they should not be able to view this library or the site itself.

Currently my client receives a 'Let us know why you need access to this site' message when sending a document (the document is sent successfully to the drop off library) through 'Sent to'.  What's the lowest permission I can give the users to this library/site to stop this message appearing?  Bear in mind that the users should not be able to see anything on this site or drop off library.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions of the Drop Off Library so all users have contribute access.

Then add a Content Organizer rule to move the documents to a separate document library that has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I have the rules set up but the documents only move once the owner of that site/library decides where the document should go (this is done through changing the properties).  Would giving 'restricted read' permission to users give them enough access to the library so they don't see this message 'Let us know...'? I can't test this at the moment as our test user accounts are locked out.

Comment: Give your users write permission to the drop off library. Make the properties required. Once they fill in the properties, the document is moved. The key is to move the document once the uploader is finished.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback Paul, but the various users shouldn't be able to complete the properties for the document in the drop off library. Only the owner of the site/library should decide where the documents should go, they do this by completing the properties.  What I have found but have not implemented is the 'Limited-access user permission lockdown mode', this may resolve my issue, I have yet to read up further on the repercussions of de-activating this feature.